Is it really easy to derive this expression for the flow of $\dot{x} = x^2$?
I'm reading the very first chapter of Dynamical Systems I: Ordinary Differential Equations and Smooth Dynamical Systems from D. V. Anosov, et al. and found myself trying not only to understand, but also to derive the expression presented for "the only possible flow" of $\dot{x} = x^2$ considering that $x(0) = 1$.
Well, it's not dificult to solve this IVP, I could express its solution as $x(t) = (1- t)^{-1}$, the maximal interval would be $I(1) = (-\infty, 1)$, of course, but then the text says it's easy to check that the only possible flow is given by the formula $g^{t}x = \frac{x}{1-tx}$. Doesn't seem so clear to me at all, another book consider the same expresson as being the "trajectory of $f$ by $x$" (considering the more general expression $\dot{x} = f(x)$) also saying that it's easy to check.
It seems I forgot about some detail in basic theory of differential equations cause it does not seem so obvious to me.

(i) We can solve $\dot{x} = x^{2}$ and $x(0) = x_{0}$ for arbitrary real $x_{0}$. (ii) The "$x$" in the flow formula should be viewed as an initial condition. That is, we might ought to denote it (at least temporarily) by $x_{0}$. <> If that helps, please feel free to post your own answer!

The flow is just a fancy way to state the solution of a IVP. Namely, if $f$ is the solution of the IVP $$ \begin{cases} f'(s)&=f(s)^2 \\ f(0)&= x. \end{cases}  $$
then we have $g^t x=f(t).$
To get the flow $g^t(x)$, you solve the ODE with initial condition $x$ at time $0$ and then evolve for time $t$. One way to visualize this is to consider a river and the trajectories of the water are the solutions of your ODE. The flow $g^t x$ asks, where do I end up if I hop in at the location $x$ and float for a time $t$ (you go with the flow, which pretty much sums up the term).

It worked! So not necessarily I should get something from $x(0) = 1$ exactly, the idea on these flow expressions is (as it should) a lot more general about the solutions, right? So $x$ in $\frac{x}{1 - xt}$ does not represent the function $x(t)$ exactly, it's being treated as a real value for the expression of $g^t x$.

Exactly. The $x$ in $\frac{x}{1-xt}$ is the initial condition. It is unfortunate notation to use $x$ as the function in the ODE and as initial condition in the flow.
